# How to detect moive ended SuRGeoNix/Flyleaf/WPF

Tags: wpf, flyleaf

How to detect movie_ended event in SuRGeoNix/Flyleaf Player.

```
        Config = new Config();
        Config.Video.BackgroundColor = Colors.DarkGray;
        Player = new Player(Config);

        InitializeComponent();
        FlyleafHost flyleafHost = new FlyleafHost();
        flyleafHost.Player = Player;
        DataContext = this;
        
        MainFrame.Children.Add(flyleafHost);

        Player.Open(@"sample.mp4");

        flyleafHost.Player.OpenPlaylistItemCompleted += Player_OpenPlaylistItemCompleted;
        flyleafHost.Player.OpenVideoStreamCompleted += Player_OpenVideoStreamCompleted; ;
```